# Multi Trigger Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, click, console-application

```
higherBet();
console.log(realtime(time));
console.log('You LOST!');
multiply();
setTimeout(function(){
       $loButton.trigger('click');
}, getRandomWait());
//$loButton.trigger('click');
```

I have `$loButton` and `$hiButton`. 
I want that to work alternately, maybe 2 times each option but I don't know how.

Comment: Please show your html

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=xHHeudTV0B

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need to repeat the callback function, then you need to use the `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. `setInterval`  allows to call a function repeatedly until cancelled and  `setTimeout` only executed the function ony **Once**.
2. You can create a counter to keep track of function executing 2 times and another variable to toggle the function execution from function1 to function 2.

A naive implementation might look like..

```js
var counter = 0;
var toggle = true;
setInterval(callback, 1000);

function callback(){
   if(counter === 2){
     counter = 0;
     toggle = !toggle;
   }
   if(toggle){
    first();
   }else{
   second();
   }
   counter++;
}

function first(){
  console.log("first");
}

function second(){
  console.log("second");
}
```